How do you greet someone at noon hours?
Noon hours refer to the hours between 12PM and 4PM. It's very common to say "Good morning" for a greeting during the hours of 6AM until 12PM or "Good afternoon" for a greeting during the hours of 4PM until 6PM, but not "Good noon". Then how do you greet someone during noon hours?

"Noon hours refer to the hours between 12PM and 4PM"...in what context? I've never heard anyone call the early afternoon "Noon Hours".

Generally speaking, from 19.00 (7pm) and onward it's "evening". When it's midday, people will either say "Good morning" or "Good afternoon",  for those  few minutes it doesn't make any difference. From 13.00 (1pm) it's "Good afternoon"

@KillingTime I've never heard of anyone calling noon hours "Early Afternoon". It's noon and then what comes after the noon - afternoon

“Noon hours” isn’t idiomatic English.

In some cultures "good morning" lasts till lunchtime, whenever that is, and "good afternoon" follows. But if you're uncertain you can always say "Hello" or (if you're 100 years ago) "Good day".

You can also say "Good day" if uncertain of the hour.

People who haven't yet had lunch often say "Good morning" after 12 noon (I refuse to say '12 p.m.). Sometimes they, or someone else, will add "It's actually afternoon now!" or similar.

@StuartF  Very true: certainly in Spain saying "good morning" lasts ᴍᴜᴄʜ later than twelve o’clock! They eat very late there, so the shops close down from 2–5ᴘᴍ. Which side of that siesta break the speaker is on determines which greeting that person uses.

@KateBunting Even in English this was traditionally how it is used: afternoon  was simply the period of day after the midday meal but before the evening meal.

@tchrist and "I'll do it this afternoon" doesn't usually mean "after 12 noon".

It's safe just to say "Hi!" Hi noon.

The noon  hour, singular. The midnight hour, singular.

@Lambie Apparently we once upon a time did use to use the noon hours in English, but most uses either long antedate our births or else are calquing something in translation.

What language first gave you those ideas, please? Even using capitals for AM/PM suggests it wasn't English…
tchrist's link baffled me, for one.
I wouldn't find it hard to accept, perhaps 11am-1pm as 'the noon hours' if that description had a recognised history.
12pm-4pm being a four-hour period vaguely suggests there might be a maritime connection, but even there 'vaguely' seems to be the operative word.

@RobbieGoodwin Here in Israel (with the Hebrew language), "Morning" is considered to be from 5 or 6 AM until 12PM and noon hours are 12 - 4 PM. We say for example (a rough translation) "3 in the noon".

Thanks and is Hebrew really so slack as to consider 'morning' moveable from 5 or 6 AM? Formal British custom insists on 6am even though informally, we might speak of '4 o'clock in the morning.'
When you say, for example (a rough translation) '3 in the noon', doesn't the whole idea fall apart without an exact translation? '3 in the noon' will prolly be understood as '3 in the afternoon' but either way, it will always mark you out as a non-native speaker, somewhat struggling.

There isn't a definitive answer to that. The formal answer is that "morning" is between sunset and when the sun is at high end when it changes to "noon". Culturally, people call different hours by different names.. for example 3AM can be called "3 at night" and sometimes "3 before morning". Some people treat 5AM as "before morning" and some as "morning", but probably 5AM in Hebrew has more "morning" usage than "before morning". With an English native speaker, I would say "3 in the afternoon", but if you say that in Hebrew, then people will probably ask "did you mean 3 in the noon"?

The problem is that your assertions are either obvious or wrong

Noon hours refer to the hours between 12PM and 4PM.

This is wrong. "Noon hours" do not exist as a concept. Where did you find this?

It's very common to say "Good morning" for a greeting during the hours of 6AM until 12PM noon

Yes, because that is the morning.

or "Good afternoon" for a greeting during the hours of 4PM until 6PM,

This is wrong.
The afternoon starts "after noon" i.e. after 12:00hrs, and continues until the sun is somewhere within an hour or so of setting or 17:43hrs if the sun will not set until after 20:00hrs. "Good evening" then becomes the greeting.
You should bear in mind that you cannot reduce "Good morning, afternoon, evening" to a mathematical formula of hours. During a year in northern Europe and other such places, the sun rises somewhere between 02:30 hrs and 08:30 hrs, and sets between 15:00hrs and 23:00hrs. You will adjust your greeting accordingly.
The morning starts as the sun rises and ends at noon. The afternoon starts at a second after noon and continues until people feel that it has become "evening."
A lot of it is subjective.

People can get too stuck literal meanings of things like afternoon having to be after exactly 12. In Spain the work day is split by a long pause for a substantial meal starting around 14:00 and running up to 3 hours before you have to go back to work and the shops reõpen. There someone says buenos días in ᴛʜᴇɪʀ mañana until they’ve had ᴛʜᴇɪʀ "midday" meal break, and after that buenas tardes for a long while till buenas noches. All these terms even loosely overlap in time by speaker: they're signalling it's the first half of ᴛʜᴇɪʀ day vs the second half, or after work and light.

@tchrist But what do they mean by buenos días? That it is a good day ... a day to be good on ...?

@tchrist, the speakers of Spanish can afford not to worry about the morning/afternoon boundary in deciding how to greet each other, because the have at their disposal the greeting buenos días. Similar greetings exist in quite a few other languages, and the learners of these languages would never feel the need to ask the question posed by the OP here. In English good day is reserved for a different purpose, which forces one to choose between good morning and good afternoon.

@jsw29 No, not really. You would never say buenos días to greet someone a las cinco de tarde, which is long past the mañana and then some. I also don’t recommend it an hour past midnight, either. They are not so obsessed with atomic time there, and retain the traditional senses in their various greetings and valedictions that have nothing to do with the calendar and clock, but only on the "time of day", which is something else altogether from a clock’s time.

You're actually wrong here. Noon is defined to be the full set of hours between mid day (12 pm) and the afternoon (4pm). Its not only a single second in the day when its exactly 12:00:00 PM

@CodeMonkey Please provide some corroboration for the claim that ."Noon is defined to be the full set of hours between mid day (12 pm) and the afternoon (4pm)"

It's a cultural thing. Each country has its own definition and here its the full set of hours between 12 and 4 pm. Regardless of definitions like that, my question is only about an English term. So let's say I want to say something similar to "good noon" at exactly 12 noon. What would I say?

@CodeMonkey "It's a cultural thing. Each country has its own definition ... So let's say I want to say something similar to "good noon" at exactly 12 noon." You would have to refer to your own culture. In Western culture that concept does not exist and thus there is no reason or way to express it.  "Each country has its own definition" That is simply untrue. Out of curiosity, which country are you referring to?

@Greybeard I'm in Israel and here we say for example "1 in the noon", not "1 in the afternoon". It's really enough to have a single example like mine to make what I said true... But again, my question is about an English term and "good noon" is not a thing in English so my question was what IS the thing to say.

@CodeMonkey In what way does this answer not address your question?

@CodeMonkey - "Good afternoon."

@CodeMonkey, given your comment, 'I'm in Israel and here we say for example "1 in the noon", not "1 in the afternoon"', it appears that you may be asking about a specific dialect of English, and probably one that most users of this site are not familiar with.  I don't know of any American or British dialect, for example, that uses the formulation, "1 in the noon".  It's permissible to ask questions about English dialects, but you'll get much more useful answers if you are clear in your question that that's what's being discussed.

It appears that the OP is seeking the exact English equivalent of tzoharaim tovim. The simple answer is that there isn't one. The standard greeting that the English speakers would use instead of it is good afternoon, but its use extends to a longer period.

@tchrist, of course, buenos días cannot be used throughout the 24 hours of day; my point was only that its not having the same  literal meaning as good morning makes it easier for the speakers of Spanish to use it in the flexible ways you describe than it would be for the speakers of English to try to stretch the use of good morning beyond noon.
